# Is extending class by class which extedning another class a good practice?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

It is missing for me extending multiple classes in Java. I would like to have defined some attributes and methods in one class to keep in one place these attributes and methods which will be used in multiple classes for a different purpose. Next, I need JPanel functionality so I need extends my class also by this class too.

I think about one solution but I am not sure it is a correct way.
Is this good practice to make something like this? I have class:

```
/*
* Class for keeping common arguments
* it is not possible to extends by two classes
* so I need extend here JPanel
*/
public class **ContentPanel** extends javax.swing.**JPanel** {
  private arg1;
  private arg2;

public void commonMethod1() {

}
/* ... */
}
```

Next, I am using this extends for some classes:

```
public class CashboxesPanel extends ContentPanel {
  /* specific class with all needed functionality, some arguments, methods used only for this class ect. */
}

public class CardIndexesPanel extends ContentPanel {
/* next specific class with implemeted original funcionality not used anywhere */
}

/* more classes */
```

I see the main disadvantages:

- it is not clear how many classes are extended by other classes. I have to check the source of extended class to check if it is not extending another,
- I don't see the most important information on top: base Class is JPanel,
- it would be terrible not clear "chain" with more classes...

Of course, interfaces can't have attributes and implemented methods so they are not usable for me.
For Abstract classes also it is not supported to extend multiple ones.

Could someone give me advice about how to deal with this Java's inheritance? ( = please say me that World is still beautiful and there is an existing "beautiful" solution for my problem...)

Comment: Your example suggests a subclass has access to a base class behavior (method) which doesn't make sense for the subclass.  See [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an opinion that `composition is better than inheritance`.

You may want to take a look on [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).